# Reemplazar un caracter específico de strings en una lista

Tags: python, lista

tengo la siguiente lista:

```
nombres = ['Sara 0 Ochoa', 'Juan Rey', 'Katherine 0 Muriel 0', 'Carlos Mario Hernandez']
print(nombres)
```

Y quiero hallar la manera en la que pueda eliminar el '0' de todos los strings que lo contengan. Es decir, quiero que mi output sea así:

```
print(nombres)

['Sara Ochoa', 'Juan Rey', 'Katherine Muriel', 'Carlos Mario Hernandez']
```

¿Qué tendría que hacer para lograr eso?

Comment: Tienes que recorrer las listas, y reemplazar ese caracter en la palabra que dices. Comienza por eso.

Comment: Lo primero es saber como reemplazar dentro de una cadena. Mira la función `replace()`. Luego aplica eso recorriendo la lista y aplicando el reemplazo a cada elemento.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estas buscando lo puedes hacer creando un nuevo array con los valores esperados, y añadir los nombres ya sin ceros al nuevo array mediante el metodo [append](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp) (para añadir los nuevos valores) y [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)(para quitar los ceros), algo así:

```
 new_array = []
 for nombre in nombres:
   result = nombre.replace(' 0', '')
   new_array.append(result)
```

El metodo `replace` recibe dos parametros, los cuales son el valor para "buscar" y el valor por el que lo va a remplazar, y el metodo `append` simplemente añade los valores a la lista.

Cuando hagas un `print` de `new_array` ya tendrás los valores sin 0

Answer (score 2):

también puedes usar compresión de listas y con la función `replace` (que reemplace el "0" por "nada"):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nombres = ['Sara 0 Ochoa', 'Juan Rey', 'Katherine 0 Muriel 0', 'Carlos Mario Hernandez']
    nombres = [item.replace("0", "") for item in nombres]
    print(nombres)
```

Tu output seria:

```
['Sara  Ochoa', 'Juan Rey', 'Katherine  Muriel ', 'Carlos Mario Hernandez']
```